# A complicated dynamic table in HTML

Tags: html, html-table, dynamic-tables

I want to create a table where the same headings gets repeated in the same tr. It is a transcript in which semesters shall come side by side in the same row and it is fully dynamic, which means different marks according to semester will be shown as well as count of subjects may differ in each semester.
Could you please help me with this?
[Here you can see the image of what the end result should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHNCa.jpg)

BTW, my approach was as follows:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered center">
  @foreach($exambatch as $exb)
  <td>
 <table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="4" style="padding:5px;">
   <b>Semester-{{ $semester->semester }}</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height:80px;">
   <b class="vertical">
     {{ Subject }}
   </b>
    </td>
    <td>
   <b class="vertical">
     Something
   </b>
    </td>
    <td>
   <b class="vertical">
     ......
   </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     ......
    </td>
  </tr>
        <!-- Load Subjects -->           
  @foreach($sub as $subject)
  <tr>
    <td>{{ $sub->sub_name }}</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

But it doesn't work at all, I tried to use a table inside the td which worked however it didn't come in a singe row. Any good approach?

Comment: you have to write static table head on the top of the dynamic value's. The Table head part are static, not dynamic. so you can write it static.

Comment: That is not an answer. Have you seen the picture?

Comment: you have missing so many closing tags, write to standard format

Comment: yes i see your picture. why you think that you have to write vertical section write to be dynamic?

Comment: It is not about table head, as far as you see in my code there is the static head but it shows according to the count of semesters.

Comment: I don't think that should be dynamic :) but the count of semesters should be dynamic. So it simply means that it shall be something like: foreach (data as something) <td>.